# Efficiently convert pandas dataframe of lists of length n to n dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe where each element is a list, or a tuple, of 3 floats.

It's not very easy to work with but it's an inherited requirement. How can I efficiently turn this into 3 separate dataframes (or n dataframes for a list of n floats)?

For example, the element in `df.iloc[0,0] == [0.23, 0.47, 0.89]`, and I want to produce `df1.iloc[0,0] == 0.23`, `df2.iloc[0,0] == 0.47`, `df3.iloc[0,0] == 0.89`.

Comment: Please share a sample of the dataframe and expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
df1, df2, df3 = (df.apply(lambda s: s.apply(lambda l: l[i])) for i in range(3))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try something like:

```
def unpack_df_to_dfs(df, num_elements):
    rowrange = range(0, len(df))
    elementrange = range(0, num_elements)
    lists = [ [[] for j in rowrange] for i in elementrange ]
    for j, row in enumerate(df.index):
        for col in df.columns:
             for i in elementrange:
                  lists[i][j].append(df.loc[row, col][i])
    return [pd.DataFrame(l) for l in lists] 

df1, df2, df3 = unpack_df_to_dfs(df, 3)
```

where `num_elements` is the number of elements in the lists or tuples in your Dataframe.

Comment: I appreciate this. This for me feels like the old fashioned way, I think the other is more pythonic (and probably faster, but I don't know)